# Determining if a file modified between 2 commits in git

Tags: git, version-control, rake

I am creating a rake task that would re-upload a file in S3 when it gets changed between HEAD and HEAD^1. Which git command should I use to do this. Does it make sense to compare the `hash-object` of those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
git log --stat HEAD^..HEAD
```

to get a list of changed files. There are other modifiers like `--raw` that will ensure full paths are shown. You can also use `--stat=200` to instruct log to assume the output is 200 characters wide and only truncate the paths then.

One thing to consider is that sometimes you won't just have one commit that's new. You will have to use `HEAD@{1}` instead of `HEAD^` to see what the last commit was. Then you need to use

```
git diff --stat HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```

`HEAD@{1}` is interpreted as "where HEAD pointed to last time". So `HEAD@{2}` would mean "where HEAD was before you changed it twice". If you look at the docs for `reflog` it would be further explained there.

For scripting, I would use `--numstat` instead of `--stat` as it does not abbreviate paths at all. You can now use this list to move just those files or delete any that are marked as deleted.

You could also compare the tree objects from each commit and there you could recursively see where SHA1s differ.

To add, if you script this within an update hook, the arguments to the hook give you both `oldref` and `newref` along with the branch name so you know exactly what the branch is currently and what it is being set to.

But this is not the ideal. If you can, try to overwrite the entire work tree and save yourself the headache.

Comment: Hey Adam.. thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate more on HEAD@{1}? What does it mean?

Comment: Check the reflog documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if a single known file was changed by a commit, you can use

```
git diff --quiet HEAD^ HEAD -- <filename>
```

Then examine the exit code to determine if it was changed, if it was the exit code will be 1 if not changed the exit code will be 0.  With this method you wouldn't need to parse the output to see if it mentions the file that you care about.

The suggestion from Adam to use `HEAD@{1}` rather than `HEAD^` is still worth considering in this case.